# Adding colour aesthetic changes position of geom_text when combined in a side-by-side boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting counts for 7 samples (1 to 9, but 4 and 5 are removed intentionally). I have a side-by-side boxplot to compare distributions under 2 conditions, D8 and D20. 
When I do not try to color the samples by their name (leave them black), the text label is on the correct side:

```
structure(list(day = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("D20", "D8"), class = "factor"), 
    bird = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "6", "7", "8", "9"
    ), class = "factor"), gene = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("male_1432600", 
    "female_1324700"), class = "factor"), count = c(89.74497, 
    109.41933, 65.998933, 148.28053, 49.756526, 87.908516, 77.77438, 
    70.26204, 86.34856, 59.0016, 112.4502, 88.07639, 102.2814, 
    99.5109, 18.75268, 36.47311, 18.856838, 24.71342, 6.420197, 
    10.342178, 0, 11.34874, 17.32301, 20.5223, 25.4421, 16.1161, 
    10.01685, 17.97708)), row.names = c(NA, -28L), class = "data.frame")

ggplot(dfm, aes(x = gene, y = count, fill = day)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0,
               alpha = 0.1,
               size = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = bird), 
            position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  theme_light()
```

[image: correct placement of sample numbers]

But when I colour the text by sample, they move horizontally so you can't see what condition that sample belongs to. Instead, it orders them numerically along the x-axis:

```
ggplot(dfm, aes(x = gene, y = count, fill = day)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0,
               alpha = 0.1,
               size = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = bird, color = bird), 
            position = position_jitterdodge()) +
  theme_light()
```

[image: text in colour, but in the wrong horizontal position]

Comment: It is to do with the random nature of `position_jitterdodge` which includes a `seed` argument to make the jitter reproducible. And discussed here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/pull/2445

Comment: @Peter hmm, within a column it does move slightly. That is not a problem. The main issue is that the color-text is ignoring the fill (day) aesthetic. They're now ordered by numerical order, not day, along the x-axis, when colour is added.

Comment: See my comment on your answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `group = day` to the `geom_text` aesthetic to keep the labels within the relevant boxplot.

Use the `jitter.width` argument to space out the labels.

```r
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(dfm, aes(x = gene, y = count, fill = day)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0,
               alpha = 0.1,
               size = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = bird), 
            position = position_jitterdodge(seed = 123)) +
  theme_light()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
  ggtitle("p1")

p2 <- ggplot(dfm, aes(x = gene, y = count, fill = day)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.size = 0,
               alpha = 0.1,
               size = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = bird, colour = bird, group = day), 
            position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 1.5, seed = 123)) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE))+
  theme_light()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  ggtitle("p2")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Something has gone wrong here. In my 2nd image, each sample number has it's own colour: 1 is red, 3 is green etc. Your p2 is not reproducing my plot. On yours, the colour is based on condition, not sample number. It needs to be ```colour = bird``` not ```colour = day```

Comment: Oh deary me, I'm being a bit slow on the uptake today! Does this do what you are looking for?

Comment: Oh much better! I feel like I should have tried the group aesthetic. This solves it! But I will nitpic now. The text seems to overlap horizontally more than before adding the colour aes. It does not spread out as much. Perhaps it's position argument I need to fine-tune.

Comment: You can adjust the `jitter.width` argument of `position_jitterdodge` to get the horizontal spacing you want. Answer adjusted but squished together graphs do not really show this well.